# .NET Framework Initialisation Error

Tags: windows-10, powershell, installation, .net-framework

I have Dell Inspiron 5481 with Windows 10 Home (10.0.19044). I keep getting these error messages.
[image]

My system has .NET Framework 4.8, so if I try to install .NET, it says you have the latest version and it does not proceed with the installation.

I do not know what Fusnbroker.exe and Google has not been helpful.

When I try to run Powershell, I get the following error message.

[image]

How can I overcome this problem?

Here is what I have tried so far.
Ran the NetFxRepairTool.exe and it came up with the following prompt.
[image]

I clicked on Next and it presented the following image. [image]

---

I then ran dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe and it came up with the following prompt.

[image]

Any answers / pointers is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like your Windows somehow is corrupted (the messages are accurate, Windows 10 does come with .NET Framework 4.6+). Maybe try the _dism scanhealth_ / _restorehealth_.

Comment: I can save you a great deal of time.  It is impossible to install .NET Framework 4.0.30319 on your machine.  Your machine has .NET Framework 4.8.x installed.  .NET Framework 4.8.x cannot be removed from your machine.  Additionally, .NET Framework 4.0.30319 cannot exist on the same machine as .NET Framework 4.8.x, .NET Framework 4.8.x replaces .NET Framework 4.0.30319.  However, your .NET installation is clearly broken, likely due to some missing registry key.  FusnBroker.exe appears to be a Dell OEM software.  I suggest reinstalling Windows 10 21H2 from within Windows in order to repair it.

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you! I am already on Widnwos 10 21H2 (I got it by doing Windows + R and then winver) and you have mentioned reinstalling Windows 10 21H2. How do I reinstall it from within Windows. Thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @DanielB Thank you! On completing the `scanhealth`, it reported *No component store creation detected.*

Comment: @Kanini - You **cannot** reinstall .NET Framework.  The only thing you can do is, mount a Windows 10 21H2 ISO, and repair install Windows. You basically keep your files, and reinstall Windows, only way I have ever seen sever .NET Framework corruption be resolved on Windows 8+

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you! That worked. Can you make it an answer so that I can accept it. :-)

Comment: There are a ton of questions that suggest that solution I will attempt to find a duplicate in a few hours. We really don't need another answer that suggests a repair in-place install.